# push the array recursively

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array  month and data
I want to push the data array for he count of the month .eg If I have 8 months I want to merge the data 8 times.

```
$month_count = 8;
$monthly_header1 = [];
$data = [
    'Budget', 
    'Revenue', 
    'EE', 
    'EN', 
    'New revenues', 
    'WIP Revenue', 
    'No SOW', 
    'Actual', 
    'DSO', 
    'Variance',
    ];
for ($i = 0; $i > $month_count; ++$i) {
    $monthly_header1[] = array_merge($monthly_header1, $data);
}
print_r($monthly_header1[]); // returns null now.need to dump the array 8 times
```

expected output

```
$monthly_header1=[
"Budget","Revenue","EE","EN","New revenues","WIP Revenue","No SOW","Actual","DSO","Variance",
"Budget","Revenue","EE","EN","New revenues","WIP Revenue","No SOW","Actual","DSO","Variance",
"Budget","Revenue","EE","EN","New revenues","WIP Revenue","No SOW","Actual","DSO","Variance",
"Budget","Revenue","EE","EN","New revenues","WIP Revenue","No SOW","Actual","DSO","Variance",
"Budget","Revenue","EE","EN","New revenues","WIP Revenue","No SOW","Actual","DSO","Variance",
"Budget","Revenue","EE","EN","New revenues","WIP Revenue","No SOW","Actual","DSO","Variance",
"Budget","Revenue","EE","EN","New revenues","WIP Revenue","No SOW","Actual","DSO","Variance",
"Budget","Revenue","EE","EN","New revenues","WIP Revenue","No SOW","Actual","DSO","Variance"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an error on your for loop and the real problem in your code is that; `array_merge` behaviour.

PHP.net say that;

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values
> of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the
> resulting array.

So you need to set the `$monthly_header1` variable with the combined array (result of `array_merge`) for each loop as you see in below.

```
$month_count=8;
$monthly_header1= array();

$data = ["Budget","Revenue","EE","EN","New revenues","WIP Revenue","No SOW","Actual","DSO","Variance"];

for ($i=0;$i<$month_count;$i++){
    $monthly_header1 = array_merge($monthly_header1,$data);
}

print_r($monthly_header1);
    /* It prints below result*/
    /* Array ( [0] => Budget [1] => Revenue [2] => EE [3] => EN [4] => New revenues [5] => WIP Revenue [6] => No SOW [7] => Actual [8] => DSO [9] => Variance [10] => Budget [11] => Revenue [12] => EE [13] => EN [14] => New revenues [15] => WIP Revenue [16] => No SOW [17] => Actual [18] => DSO [19] => Variance [20] => Budget [21] => Revenue [22] => EE [23] => EN [24] => New revenues [25] => WIP Revenue [26] => No SOW [27] => Actual [28] => DSO [29] => Variance [30] => Budget [31] => Revenue [32] => EE [33] => EN [34] => New revenues [35] => WIP Revenue [36] => No SOW [37] => Actual [38] => DSO [39] => Variance [40] => Budget [41] => Revenue [42] => EE [43] => EN [44] => New revenues [45] => WIP Revenue [46] => No SOW [47] => Actual [48] => DSO [49] => Variance [50] => Budget [51] => Revenue [52] => EE [53] => EN [54] => New revenues [55] => WIP Revenue [56] => No SOW [57] => Actual [58] => DSO [59] => Variance [60] => Budget [61] => Revenue [62] => EE [63] => EN [64] => New revenues [65] => WIP Revenue [66] => No SOW [67] => Actual [68] => DSO [69] => Variance [70] => Budget [71] => Revenue [72] => EE [73] => EN [74] => New revenues [75] => WIP Revenue [76] => No SOW [77] => Actual [78] => DSO [79] => Variance ) */
```

Answer (score 0):

First your loop is not correct, need to change loop condition

```
for ($i = 0; $i > $month_count; ++$i)
```

to

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $month_count; ++$i)
```

then use implode function to merge all data as single array

```
<?php
$month_count = 8;
$monthly_header1 = [];
$data = [
'Budget',
'Revenue',
'EE',
'EN',
'New revenues',
'WIP Revenue',
'No SOW',
'Actual',
'DSO',
'Variance',
];
for ($i = 0; $i < $month_count; ++$i) {
$monthly_header1 = array_merge($monthly_header1, $data);
}

$implode_array = implode(',', $monthly_header1);
$format_aray = explode('/', $implode_array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($format_aray);
?>
```

Then output will be single array like this your output